# Filter on LOOKUPVALUE (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create a new column in TABLE B to sum up the total weight from Table A. But I don't want the sum value are copying to every single row in TABLE B (Based on ID). I just want to VLOOKUP the value to every first of the ID (Num = 1)

Expectation

[image: TABLE a]

[image: TABLE b]

Thank for your attention. Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have column Num in place? Or you just showing that just to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Column = 
VAR _1 =
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX (
            FILTER ( t1, t1[id] = MAXX ( FILTER ( t2, t2[num] = 1 ), t2[id] ) ),
            t1[val]
        )
    ) 
RETURN
    _1
```

[image: Solution]